# is it possible to trade in the digital version of Pokemon Gold?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

I've just bought and downloaded Pokemon Gold for my 3DS.

Is it possible for me to trade pokemon with other players somehow? Say, if I wanted an Alakazam or something, which would require trading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, From the press release it says you can use the wireless features just as was done in Red/Blue/Yellow with Gold and Silver.

> As with the Virtual Console versions of Pokemon Red and Blue, and Pokemon Yellow: Special Pikachu Edition, Gold and Silver will be compatible with the 3DS wireless communication feature, which means Link Trades and Link Battles between the Virtual Console versions.

[[Source]](https://www.vg247.com/2017/06/06/pokemon-gold-and-silver-to-release-on-3ds-virtual-console-in-september/)

Comment: Ah okay! Did not know that. Not even about the RBY version. Thanks!

Comment: Happy Collecting/Trading/Battling ;)